# How to convert f64 into String and parse back into f64?

Tags: string, parsing, serialization, rust, numbers

```rust
let s = format!("{}", t);
let x = s.parse::<f64>();
```

If `t` is of type `f64`, is there any case that the parsing back to `f64` would fail?

Comment: Do you mean that it must parse to something that compares truthfully with `==` to the original? Or only that the parsing never be `Err`? Because `NaN != NaN` in floats to begin with.

Comment: The second one.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't seem so. This program covers all interesting edge cases, e.g. NaN, Infinity, Negative Infinity, etc, and it compiles and runs fine without panicking:

```rust
fn check_serialization_eq(nums: &[f64]) {
    for num in nums {
        let s = num.to_string();
        let x = s.parse::<f64>().unwrap();
        dbg!(num, x);
    }
}

fn main() {
    check_serialization_eq(&[
        f64::MIN,
        f64::MAX,
        f64::NAN,
        f64::INFINITY,
        f64::NEG_INFINITY,
        f64::EPSILON,
    ]);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=991b3fd3f8b148daad483da18529cc26)

Comment: Note that [previous versions](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/27307) of Rust's stdlib would emit string-representations that could not round-trip. There are probably still edge cases and I'd chose not to rely on this behavior if possible.

Comment: Also, don't forget that in general, comparing floating numbers is tricky, even for regular-looking numbers! Plus there is a WIDE variety of different `NaN`s/infinities.